# webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting started with Selenium for python and have this:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging", "enable-automation"])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

I want to open Chrome browser with my accounts logged in, so i use
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')`

Browser opens, but it gives this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When I tried to delete
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')`
it works, but I really need to have my accounts logged in

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This argument helped me:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```